# Convert string in Chinese character to Unicode in Java

Tags: java, unicode

Suppose there is a string in Chinese Charater "你好", the correct result for converting the string into Unicode is "\u4f60\u597d", the result i got from the code below is "\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd". Why???

Java code:

```
String str = "你好";
public String testEncoding(String str) {
    String result = "";
    for(char ch : str.toCharArray())
        result += "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(ch | 0x10000).substring(1);
    System.out.print(result);
    return result;
}

String text = testEncoding("你好");
public static void input(String text){
    execShellCmd(String.format("am broadcast -a ADB_INPUT_TEXT --es msg \'%s\'", text));
}

private static void execShellCmd(String cmd) {
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
        dataOutputStream.write(cmd.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        dataOutputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I set text = "\u4f60\u597d", the terminal displays "你好".

Comment: Is your terminal configured to support UTF-8?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that source file encoding does not correspond the encoding used by compiler. Use `javac -encoding utf-8` or `javac -encoding gb2312` or whatever depending on your source file encoding.

Answer (score -2):

java demo please see:

```
    /**
        * 
        * strings to codepoint
        * @param str ab一2仯34
        * @return \\u61\\u62\\u4e00\\u32\\u2b802\\u4eef\\u33\\u2b82f\\u34\\u34
    */
    public static String stringToCodePoints(String str) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        str.codePoints().forEach(cp -> stringBuilder.append("\\u").append(Integer.toHexString(cp)));
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Please remove chinese characters from your code sample (and translate them) - many people on other continents just don't understand them :)